# Sumar el resultado de una consulta

Tags: sql, oracle

Quiero sumar los datos de *amount* que me devuelve la selección. Dejo mi código:

```sql
SELECT 
    ILA.INVOICE_ID,
    ILA.LINE_NUMBER,
    ILA.AMOUNT,
    NVL(TO_CHAR(ILA.QUANTITY_INVOICED),'SIN REGISTRO') Quantity,
    NVL(TO_CHAR(ILA.UNIT_PRICE),'SIN REGISTRO') Price
FROM AP_INVOICE_LINES_ALL ILA
```

Comment: `SUM()` no te funciona?

Comment: Cuales son los datos que arroja la consulta?, que has intentado?, se mas especifico.

Comment: SUM YA INTENTE PERO TOMA EL MISMO DATO Y NO SUMA

Comment: LOS DATOS QUE REGRESA SOLO SON UNOS CMAPOS SELECCIONADOS PERO LO QUE QUIERO ES SUMAR ESOS DATOS DEVUELTOS POR ESA QUERY

Comment: Por eso mismo, edita tu pregunta y adjunta que datos trae consigo ese campo, por si se necesita hacer un **decode** o solo la suma, no podemos adivinar, lo simple es **ILA.sum(AMOUNT)**, como te menciono @Isanchezo.

Comment: Realiza lo que te aconsejan arriba, sería bueno que coloques el error y algún ejemplo mínimo verificable, como en DBFiddle.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra los errores que has tenido, y en lo posible también las estructuras de tu tabla, tal como te han indicado en los comentarios. Por último, recuerda que mayúsculas en internet = GRITAR.